# Does cold temperatures hurt my guitars if stored in a non heated place through the northeastern winter??

Tags: electric-guitar

will cold temperatures hurt my guitars if stored in a non heated place through the northeastern winter?? I'd like to know if I need to move them to the house?

Comment: What kinds of guitars? Either way, if there is room in the house, I would move them in so you don't have to wonder.

Comment: Where in the northeast? What sort of temperatures/humidity? Big daily changes?

Answer (score 3):

Quick changes in temperature as well as certain levels of humidity can damage a guitar. Since you won't be able to control those changes outside, your guitar will be safer at room temperature.

Answer (score 2):

**Which** northeast are we talking about? America? Europe? Asia? Switzerland?? I'm assuming USA because you assume that it's implicit, pardon my stereotyping.

It's usually temperature and humidity **changes** you need to avoid, but also beware of keeping your house too arid if you are keeping it inside. Too dry air can cause fretboards to shrink, or acoustic guitars to crack, neither of which you want!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your guitar is made out of whether it hurts the actual instrument.  It your guitar is made of wood, you absolutely must not let it freeze or experience massive changes in temperature (it will become brittle and structurally unsound, plus start to sound much more tinny).

If your guitar is an electric guitar and relies on pickups rather than resonating itself then you only have to worry about the strings (the body may become more brittle, but this is not related to the musical quality).  You will absolutely ruin the strings on your guitar (of any kind) if you let them experience temperature variance of 35F or more - this is a simple mechanical fact rather than a musical one (true even without a winter - they will become warped and stretch beyond the ability to tune for any duration).

Comment: First time I've heard about strings warping and stretching due to extreme temperature swings. Where did that information come from?

Comment: From what I remember, the issue is similar to rapidly stretching your strings (pre-stretching, usually by pulling up on them to stretch them out). By not having regular tension across the length of the string you cause thin spots which causes loading, which causes a warble in the string creating tone decay as the vibrations slow down (pitch changes from when you pick it to when the string stops vibrating.) You can often hear this effect on old strings that causes difficulty in tuning well. I'm not sure the effect of a rapid temperature change could cause the same thing though.

Comment: This whole answer seems quite dubious to me. That about the strings is pretty much just wrong (I know at least carbon fibre instruments have no difficulty whatsoever with large temperature swings, despite using the same steel strings). Wood definitely does respond to temperature and humidity, but I'd be surprised if freezing would be such a problem per se (consider that living spruce is perfectly happy at boreal conditions). As others have said, it's mostly _rapid changes_ that are an issue. Though that too is often exaggerated.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: wide variance in temperature applies considerable fatigue factor to wire - how much and the impact differ based on the temperature and the alloy.  This is not a musical question, it's a materials science one.  Wide swings in temperature will affect the functional lifetime of your strings, and over 30-35F it will do so significantly (at least with common alloys - if someone starts making strings out of new materials you'd have to look up the fatigue research on those materials).

Comment: To be clear, the wire in question for guitar strings is actually wound *around* a nylon (or steel, for electric usually) thread, and the effects of temperature on nylon I am not aware (although I'm sure you can find research on this topic).  The effects of temperature on the metal that is wound around the string are what affect the functional lifetime (how long it stays in tune, and how much variance exists over the length of the string).

Comment: @NickBastin much the same steel alloys are routinely used in industrial applications which experience temperature swings of _hundreds_ of Kelvins, that in some cases probably multiple times per hour, and the machinery is still supposed to last for years. Sure, there's a limit to what swings are safe, but 20 K is nowhere near it. — What do mean, about nylon now? This question seems to be about steelstring guitars. Nylon strings actually are more temperature-sensitive in my experience, albeit just with respect to tuning stability.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: I'm not sure about the OP string type - they don't actually specify what kind of guitar (nylon never for electric, but common for classical).  You'd have to know the specs for a given string to be sure, but in my experience the nickel-plated steel wind used for most guitar strings is not a high temperature alloy (which is often electroless, which makes it too brittle to be used for such an application).